# inMobi banner ad not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, inmobi

I have integrated inMobi to my iOS game. InMobi test mode showed integration successful banner ad. The game is approved by app store then I verified link of the game in inmobi site and disabled test mode.

But now strange thing happens with InMobi, it doesn't show any ads in game. But in the InMobi site it counts impression counts and clicks. 
Does anyone know this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basic question, but have you added the adView as a subView? If impressions and clicks are being recorded, then maybe its a view-related problem ?

Comment: I agree with Sohan. Can you give the view hierarchy?